# How to create an advanced wizard form usingcard layout on Extjs 3.2?

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, wizard

There was an Ext.ux.wizard for extjs 2.0 which we could create wizard like forms for extjs and easily validate form elements when user clicked (eg)next button.see demo here: http://www.siteartwork.de/wizardcomponent_demo . On extjs 3.2 there is card layout which helps creating wizards.see demo: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html .
Code:

```
/*  
 * ================  CardLayout config (Wizard)  =======================  
 */  
var cardWizard = {  
    id:'card-wizard-panel',  
    title: 'Card Layout (Wizard)',  
    layout:'card',  
    activeItem: 0,  
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px',  
    defaults: {border:false},  
    bbar: ['->', {  
        id: 'card-prev',  
        text: '&laquo; Previous',  
        handler: cardNav.createDelegate(this, [-1]),  
        disabled: true  
    },{  
        id: 'card-next',  
        text: 'Next &raquo;',  
        handler: cardNav.createDelegate(this, [1])  
    }],  
    items: [{  
        id: 'card-0',  
        html: '<h1>Welcome to the Demo Wizard!</h1><p>Step 1 of 3</p><p>Please click the "Next" button to continue...</p>'  
    },{  
        id: 'card-1',  
        html: '<p>Step 2 of 3</p><p>Almost there.  Please click the "Next" button to continue...</p>'  
    },{  
        id: 'card-2',  
        html: '<h1>Congratulations!</h1><p>Step 3 of 3 - Complete</p>'  
    }]  
};
```

but there seems no validations when i click next or there is no submit button when i reach last step of wizard.does anybody have any examples on a more developed wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this thread - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121059-Making-a-Wizard&highlight=wizard
Or use ready extension - http://code.google.com/p/ext-ux-wiz/ (it seems to be working with ExtJS 3.2), the forum thread for it is here - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?36627-2.1-Ext.ux.Wiz-a-wizard-component-for-Ext-JS/page25

Comment: Thanks dear zihotki for your fruitful answer.i checked ext-ux-wiz repository and the latest commit was on jan 2010:added Ext 3.0.3 compatibility.i will check it to see if it works on 3.2 or not.